# Replace substring into html code

Tags: twig

In this block I'm need to replace substring `http` to `https`

`{{ system.getBlock('info-product-carousel')|raw }}`

I try to use replace like this:

`|replace({'%http%': "https"})`

But this construction don't work in my situation:

`{{ system.getBlock('info-product-carousel')|raw|replace({'%http%': "https"})} }}`

I somewhere was mistaken, but I don't no twig and couldn't find the solution by myself.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It would be better if you checkout [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for future endeavor at Stack overflow.Great question tend to provide quicker, better answers from the community -Thank you

Comment: If you need to replace `http` with `https`, then why are you using `%http%`? Also if you are really doing this in the view the statement should be `{{ system.getBlock('info-product-carousel')|replace({'http://': "https://"} | raw }}`, otherwise `https` would've become `httpss`

Comment: thank you. 
you missed symbol ")" , but anyway I still have this old problem..
I try to use that:
{{ system.getBlock('info-product-carousel')|replace({'http://': "https://"})|raw }}

but it's not work and I see anything (white space).